# Show the bottom bar on every view

Tags: iphone, uiview

I want to have this bottom bar on every UIViewController, I took this as tab bar first, but then I changed it to UIView because I need to scroll the bar as it contains more buttons, but now the issue is how to show this bar on every UIViewController and where I should declare this.
Can anyone guide me for that.

Thanks in advance.

[image: UIview]

This way I set UIView as bottom bar in one of UIViewController.

```
viewBotBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 380, 320, 79)];
viewBotBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1aa.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:viewBotBar];
```

Comment: add your tab bar in appDelegate class and set property then as per your requirement you can show and hide that.

Comment: actually i need to scroll the bar and i think that's not possible in case of tab bar that's why i took uiview.

Answer (score 3):

hi my dear Friend i just google it and i found Best tutorial for you please download bellow link's example:-

https://github.com/a1phanumeric/PeekabooTabBarController

hear is the demo Image:-

[image]

Hope its helps you al the very best :)

Comment: Thanks buddy it seems nice, i am getting through this.

Answer (score 1):

just add this view in window for every view like bellow..

write this method in `AppDelegate.m` file and call this method after add rootViewController..

```
-(void)addCustomBottomBar{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.window cache:YES];

    viewBotBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 380, 320, 79)];
    viewBotBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1aa.png"]];
    [self.window addSubview:viewBotBar];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:viewBotBar];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

**UPDATE:**

see these links for Custom TabBar..

1. [Custom TabBar](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar)
2. [RXCustomTabBar](https://github.com/rumex/RXCustomTabBar)

Comment: @iPhone just change the frame of viewBotBar and add this to window ..now use this above method dude...

Comment: also just call this method with create the object of AppDelegate and then call it like AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;[appDelegate addCustomBottomBar];

Comment: Its working but the action of buttons, i am using self.navigationController to move to other view on button click, but its not working in delegate class.

Comment: from which class you want to move to another view??

Comment: hey i think when user swipe up the view at that time your this tabbar view on the screen right??

Comment: There are several buttons on viewBotBar, their action is to move to the respected view controller. So the "self.navigationController pushVie....." command is not working in delegate itself, as viewBotBar, buttons and their actions are also declared in delegate now.

Comment: Bottom bar is showing but how can i check whether it is showing on all views or not.

Comment: @iPhone just push all views from another views .. it must show on every view bcoz we add this in window like tabbar so its shows in every view .. may be not displayed on that view which we present from viewController just try it dude.. :)

Comment: How can i add buttons on the view when it is declared in delegate class

Comment: jus add as a subview or just take UIView from xib and just set frame with your requirement after that when you call this method then your view displayed very well dude .. otherwise use customTabbar for that

Comment: what about My answer paras sir... ?  hahaha

Comment: oh ho nice answer dude but what about my answer its also some helpful or not??.. :) +1

Comment: @iPhone see these two links for custom tabbar http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar and 
https://github.com/rumex/RXCustomTabBar

Comment: @NitinGohel what about my answer also dude??

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Access the window object like

```
 UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
viewBotBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 380, 320, 79)];
viewBotBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1aa.png"]];
window addSubView:viewBotBar];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one class file. Then implement one method for custom Tab & try to call this method on every View controller. Then add this bar with object of that class.